# Ionic 1 - npm install error - unknown revision in working tree

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I get the following error for installing npm packages.

```
D:\Mobile Project>npm install
npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@0.3.13: Please use gulp-clean-css
npm WARN deprecated cordova-plugin-console@1.1.0: This plugin has been 
deprecated since it is now included in the latest versions of cordova-ios
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 master: fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': 
unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 master: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, 
like this:
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 master: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- 
[<file>...]'
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 master:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\naveenkumar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
 cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 master
npm ERR! fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in 
the working tree.
npm ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
npm ERR! 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Mobile Project\npm-debug.log
```

**Packages.json dependencies:**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-disableshaketoedit": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^2.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git",
    "cordova-uglify": "^0.2.9",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "git+https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the version for the following dependencies as suggested by VS code intellisense solved it. Hope it might help others. :)

```
"dependencies": {
  ....
  "cordova-plugin-x-toast":"^2.6.0",
  "cordova-sqlite-storage":"^2.1.2",
  "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner":"^7.0.0",
  ....
}
```

Thanks to those who tried to solve my issue.